# What does the characteristic polynomial of an element in a finite flat $R$-algebra tell you?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, and $B$ a finite locally free $R$-algebra. Since $B$ is locally free, for every $b\in B$, multiplication by $b$ gives an $R$-linear endomorphism of $B$ as a locally free $R$-module. Thus, we may consider its characteristic polynomial

$$P_b(T) := \text{det}(T-b)\in R[T]$$

Ie, we cover Spec $R$ with open neighborhoods $U_i$ where $B$ is free, and on each $U_i$ we pick a basis, compute the characteristic polynomial there, and using basis-invariance of the char poly, we glue them together to obtain the char poly "$P_b(T) := \text{det}(T-b)$" in $R[T]$.

This construction seems so natural and yet so strange at the same time.

In terms of algebraic geometry, what does this characteristic polynomial represent/tell you?

Is there a good reference/book that discusses the properties of this characteristic polynomial in this setting? (I'm of course familiar with the situation where $R$ is a field. I'm just wondering what carries over from the field case to our case here).

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932006/characteristic-polynomial-of-an-element-of-a-finite-flat-r-algebra

Comment: @user26857 Is that against the rules? Should I delete one of them?

Comment: Locally free modules allow for [determinants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449010/determinant-of-locally-free-sheaf), so the idea isn't entirely bonkers. But note that on different connected components of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, the characteristic polynomial will have different degrees.